# Removing duplicates from the Attribute table by expression in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, delete, duplication, qgsexpression

I have some duplicates in my data attribute table, you can see below:

[image]

I used the following formula:

```
count(1, "Site ID") > 1
```

based on this question: [Identifying duplicate attributes in field using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27822/identifying-duplicate-attributes-in-field-using-qgis)

But as you can see I have just the duplicate values selected. When I click on any of them in order to delete it, the rest of the selected stuff disappears (is deselected).

I am wondering about the option, which would allow me to remove these duplicates by some expression.

A similar problem was considered in these threads:

- [Removing duplicate records in the Attribute table using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/421904/removing-duplicate-records-in-the-attribute-table-using-qgis)
- [Selecting duplicate records in PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/225563/selecting-duplicate-records-in-pyqgis)

where the Python approach was suggested.

I personally think, the delete duplicate features [Removing overlapping/duplicate polygons in the same layer using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133207/removing-overlapping-duplicate-polygons-in-the-same-layer-using-qgis) is not the best option here, because I have to base my selection on just one column in the data attribute table. How can I sort it out?

Comment: Sorry, the question is not clear: what is your problem? You have a selection and don't know how to delete? Or you don't know how to generate an appropriate selection? Based on which fields exactly duplicates should be identiefied?

Comment: I have the selection and I don't know how to delete just 1 record from 2. As you can see I have some of them doubled and I need one of them deleted for each case. I have them 27.

Comment: Did you try the ["Delete duplicates by attribute"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#delete-duplicates-by-attribute)?

Comment: @Taras I am not the best at reading the references and here is the problem. If you could explain to me how to read these, I would be really grateful.

Comment: If there are two with the same Pole ID, which one should be deleted?

Comment: The second one  could be deleted because it's more poor with other data

Comment: This is a great suggestion, @Taras, didn't know that tool. It's not at all difficult to understand, just open and run it, MKR - no need to read much ;-)

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not an expression, but there is a tool in QGIS for deleting duplicates called ["Delete duplicates by attribute"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#delete-duplicates-by-attribute).

> Deletes duplicate rows by only considering the specified field /
> fields. The first matching row will be retained, and duplicates will
> be discarded.
>
> Optionally, these duplicate records can be saved to a separate output
> for analysis.

Let's assume there is a polygon layer *'poly_test'* with several duplicates, see the image below.

[image: input1]

After applying the algorithm with these settings, where the `"id"` field was used as `Fields to match duplicates by`

[image: window1]

The following output will appear

[image: output1]

---

If there is a need to delete duplicates based on its data *"poorness"*, proceed with the following workflow.

Let's assume there is a polygon layer *'poly_test'* with several duplicates, see the image below.

[image: input2]

**Step 1.** Create a field `"Quality"` using the following expression:

```
array_count(array("Data1", "Data2", "Data3"), '')
```

[image: step_1]

**Step 2.** Apply the ["Extract by expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#extract-by-expression) with the following expression:

```
"Quality" = minimum("Quality", group_by:="id")
```

[image: window2]

[image: step_2]

**Step 3.** Finally apply the "Delete duplicates by attribute" algorithm (with the `"id"` field as `Fields to match duplicates by`) and get the output like this:

[image: step_3]

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have duplicate values in field `"value"` and want to keep just one of the duplicate: the one with the smallest `"id"` value: use ["Select by expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#selecting-features) with this expression:

```
array_contains (
    with_variable (
        'array',
        array_agg( 
            $id, 
            group_by:="Site ID", 
            order_by:=$id
        ),
        array_remove_all( 
            @array, 
            array_first( @array)
        )
    ),
    $id
)
```

[image]

Comment: I tried: array_contains (
    with_variable (
        'array',
        array_agg( 
            'Site ID', 
            group_by:='Site ID', 
            order_by:='Site ID'
        ),
        array_remove_all( 
            @array, 
            array_first( @array)
        )
    ),
    'Site ID'
)

and it selects nothing, as  have the "false" in the result

Comment: That's why I asked based on what you want to identify duplicates - it seems only based on `Site Id`. Try: `array_contains ( with_variable ( 'array', array_agg( 'Site ID', group_by:='Site ID', order_by:=$id ), array_remove_all( @array, array_first( @array) ) ), $id)`

Comment: Still no reaction, I have even created the id column not existing before, but the result is the same.

Comment: Sorry, did not have access to QGIS when I wrote my last comment. I mean: take my initial expression and replace all `id` by `$id` and `value` by `Site Id`, thus the expression should look like: `array_contains (
    with_variable (
        'array',
        array_agg( 
            $id, 
            group_by:=Site ID, 
            order_by:=$id
        ),
        array_remove_all( 
            @array, 
            array_first( @array)
        )
    ),
    $id
)`